# Rails 3 - list the groups that the current user is not already a member of

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I'm converting an app from php to rails, and I'm still learning my way around rails and AR.

**Simply**: I want to list the groups that the current user is not already a member of.

**Failed Approach**:

1. `Cause.select('causes.*').joins(:users).group('causes.id').where("cause_user_memberships.user_id
   NOT IN (?)", current_user.id)`
2. `Cause.select('causes.*').joins(:users).group('causes.id').where("cause_user_memberships.user_id NOT IN  (SELECT cause_user_memberships.cause_id FROM cause_user_memberships WHERE cause_user_memberships.user_id =(?))", current_user.id)`
3. Many more...

Thanks for your help!

## Some info about models

**User.rb (snippet)**

```
has_many :cause_user_memberships
has_many :causes, :through => :cause_user_memberships
```

**Cause.rb**

```
attr_accessible :title, :location, :description,...
has_many :cause_user_memberships
has_many :users, :through => :cause_user_memberships
```

**Cause_User_Membership.rb** (<--probably not my best model name)

```
    # == Schema Information
#
# Table name: cause_user_memberships
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer          not null
#  cause_id   :integer          not null
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class CauseUserMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cause_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :cause, :counter_cache => :users_count 
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :cause
      validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope =>[:cause_id]

end
```

## Update: Follow up

Derp, you're right it worked! Thanks!

**Small follow up**, the query times seem pretty long. Does this indicate a problem? I have less than 20 records in each table. (Below are 2 query results, one that includes the geocoder gem I intend to use and another that doesn't. Sorry if it's a little messy.)

**In Rails Console:**

```
Cause Load (1003.0ms)  SELECT "causes".* FROM "causes" LEFT JOIN cause_user_memberships ON cause_user_memberships.cause_id = causes.id AND cause_user_memberships.user_id = 1 WHERE (cause_user_memberships.id IS NULL)

EXPLAIN (34.3ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT "causes".* FROM "causes" LEFT JOIN cause_user_memberships ON cause_user_memberships.cause_id = causes.id AND cause_user_memberships.user_id = 1 WHERE (cause_user_memberships.id IS NULL)
```

**QUERY PLAN**

```
 Hash Right Join  (cost=10.45..37.99 rows=1 width=3168)
   Hash Cond: (cause_user_memberships.cause_id = causes.id)
   Filter: (cause_user_memberships.id IS NULL)
   ->  Seq Scan on cause_user_memberships  (cost=0.00..27.50 rows=7 width=8)
         Filter: (user_id = 1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=10.20..10.20 rows=20 width=3168)
         ->  Seq Scan on causes  (cost=0.00..10.20 rows=20 width=3168)
(7 rows)
```

**With Geocoder on local host:**

```
User Load (18.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Cause Load (49.6ms)  SELECT causes.*, 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((40.714269 - causes.lat) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(40.714269 * PI() / 180) * COS(causes.lat * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-74.005972 - causes.lng) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) AS distance, CAST(DEGREES(ATAN2( RADIANS(causes.lng - -74.005972), RADIANS(causes.lat - 40.714269))) + 360 AS decimal) % 360 AS bearing FROM "causes" LEFT JOIN cause_user_memberships 
 ON cause_user_memberships.cause_id = causes.id 
 AND cause_user_memberships.user_id = 1 WHERE (causes.lat BETWEEN 36.37231550667456 AND 45.05622249332544 AND causes.lng BETWEEN -79.73435509229111 AND -68.27758890770889 AND 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((40.714269 - causes.lat) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(40.714269 * PI() / 180) * COS(causes.lat * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-74.005972 - causes.lng) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) <= 300) AND (cause_user_memberships.id IS NULL) ORDER BY distance ASC
```

`Completed 200 OK in 1068ms (Views: 49.1ms | ActiveRecord: 791.4ms)`

Comment: Left joins are generally slower than inner joins. You may see some improvement by applying indexes on the `cause_id` and `user_id` columns on the join table. In the query plan where it says `Seq Scan` it means postgres is just looping through the table until it finds the results.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will do it tonight. Doesn't 1000ms seem excessively long? When I did almost the same thing with php/MySQL and no active record it would be orders of magnitudes quicker. Scratching my head why there is such a big difference.

Comment: It does seem a bit long. But there are many variables. ActiveRecord builds copies of the objects in memory so there is overhead for that which isn't directly related to the query speed. You could check the query in a SQL console like pgAdmin in order to remove ActiveRecord as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails the `joins(:symbol)` statement turns into an inner join which is not suited for finding relations that don't exist. You can write the join by hand in order to make it a left join:

```
Cause.joins("""
  LEFT JOIN cause_user_memberships 
  ON cause_user_memberships.cause_id = causes.id 
  AND cause_user_memberships.user_id = #{current_user.id}
""").where("cause_user_memberships.id IS NULL")
```

**UPDATED**

The inner join will prevent the creation of a set of Causes that don't have a mapping to the given user. For example:

```
Causes
id | name
============
1  | Cause 1
2  | Cause 2

Users
id | name
============
1  | User 1

Cause User Memberships
id | user_id | cause_id
=======================
1  | 1       | 1

SELECT *
FROM causes
INNER JOIN cause_user_memberships
ON cause_user_memberships.cause_id = causes.id
AND cause_user_memberships.user_id = 1
```

Will return

```
causes.id | causes.name | cause_user_memberships.id | cause_user_memberships.user_id | cause_user_memberships.cause_id
===========================================================================================================================
1         | Cause 1     | 1                         | 1                              | 1
```

Which you can't perform any more logic on in order to tease out the causes the user doesn't belong to.

```
SELECT *
FROM causes
LEFT JOIN cause_user_memberships
ON cause_user_memberships.cause_id = cause.id
AND cause_user_memberships.user_id = 1
```

Will return

```
causes.id | causes.name | cause_user_memberships.id | cause_user_memberships.user_id | cause_user_memberships.cause_id
===========================================================================================================================
1         | Cause 1     | 1                         | 1                              | 1
2         | Cause 2     | null                      | null                           | null
```

In this case all the Causes will get a row whether they match a record in the `cause_user_memberships` table or not. Now you can apply additional conditions to tease out the causes the user doesn't belong to (where cause_user_membership.id is null).

Comment: his relation does exist he has a has_many :users so the joins should work no?

Comment: @LeoCorrea The main problem is the `inner join`. It cannot return a `cause_user_membership` record that does not exist. I will add some more to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Quick follow up above